# GNU Emacs can't work on X11 and crashes with a message "Font `Ubuntu Mono 13'

Tags: xorg, fonts, emacs

I got an GNU Emacs' problem, it can't work  on X11 and crashes with a message "Font `Ubuntu Mono 13' is not defined" but it works fine without X, more Xemacs can run without problem, GNU Emacs is a version 23.2.1 and Xemacs is a [version 21.4.22; August 2010]

I saw the kotnik's post ont the 2011-11-21 22:45:49 and my problem is not related with these  `ttf-ubuntu-font-family` as they are installed and it makes no help then  i have no .emacs file and .emacs.d/ folder is empty.

The problem seems to be related with my user's profile cause it works fine with an other user's profile on the same system (the .emacs.d/ folder on that account is the same than mine.

Comment: Try to start emacs with `-q` and with `-Q` if the problem goes away with `-q` it's your fault (your configuration under .emacs or .emacs.d) if the problem goes away with `-Q` then there is a problem with your system configuration or your X resources (something in .Xresources or /etc/)

Comment: I tried this but none of them worked

Answer (score 3):

Try adding following line into your `~/.Xdefaults` file (if not exists create one with `touch .Xdefaults`):

```
   emacs.font:Monospace 12.
```

See `man emacs` for details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an emacs expert but check you .emacs file the problem may be the combination of font and size is not supported. The line

(set-default-font "Monospace-12")

is in my .emacs file (in you home/user directory just in case you don't know) if you have no default font set try this one it works fine on my system.

Comment: Just adding that line (set-default-font "Monospace-12") did'nt worked but that's the good way, i tried also launching emacs with the command : 'emacs -fn "Monospace-12"` and this one worked. Finally, i could anyway create a bashn alias to emacs with it.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely obvious at first: you need to install the font file you get from font.ubuntu.com on the machine on which you are running emacs, not as I would have thought, on the machine where the Xserver is.  I ran into this running emacs via ssh.

```
mkdir -p ~/.fonts
cd ~/.fonts
wget http://font.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-font-family-0.80.zip
unzip ubuntu-font-family-0.80.zip
fc-cache -f
```

It is a really nice looking font. I never figured out where the setting was, but once
I had emacs started, was able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to stem from a users home directory that had been run under Ubuntu 11.10 or higher that set the **gconf** setting for `/desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name` to `Ubuntu Mono 13`. Setting this to something that is available fixes the issue.

```
gconftool-2 -g /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name
Ubuntu Mono 13
```

Set it to Monospace-12 or whatever you would like:

```
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name
Monospace-12

gconftool-2 -g /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name
Monospace-12
```